# Class does not conform to Encodable

Tags: swiftui

However, getting an error message that says that my class  'Expenses' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable' & Type 'Expenses' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

```
import Foundation

class Expenses : ObservableObject, Codable  {
    
    @Published var items : [ExpenseItem] {
        // Step 1 creat did set on publsihed var.
        didSet {
            let encoder = JSONEncoder()
            if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(items) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "Items")
            }
        }
    }

    init() {
        if let items = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "Items") {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder(
            if let decoded = try?
                decoder.decode([ExpenseItem].self, from: items) {
                self.items = decoded
                return
            }
        }
        self.items = []
    }     
}
```

my expense item is flagged as

```
struct ExpenseItem : Identifiable, Codable   {
    let id = UUID()
    let name : String
    let type : String
    let amount : Int       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Conformance to `Encodable`/`Decodable` is auto-synthesized when all stored properties conform to `Encodable`/`Decodable`, but using a property wrapper on a property means that now the property wrapper type needs to conform to `Encodable`/`Decodable`.

`@Published` property wrapper doesn't conform. It would have been nice to just implement conformance on the `Published` type itself, but unfortunately it doesn't expose the wrapped value, so without using reflection (I've seen suggestions online), I don't think it's possible.

You'd need to implement the conformance manually:

```
class Expenses : ObservableObject {
   @Published var items : [ExpenseItem]

   // ... rest of your code
}

extension Expense: Codable {
   enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
      case items
   }
    
   func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
      var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      try container.encode(self.items, forKey: .items)
   }

   required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      var container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      self.items = try container.decode([ExpenseItem].self, forKey: .items)
   }      
}
```

Comment: I thought i had implemented it manually with the endorser method and the initializer decoder

Comment: What's "endorser"? Do you mean "encoder"? You haven't implemented either `encode(to:)` or `init(from:)` in `Expenses`. Typically, the compiler synthesizes it for you, but `@Published` property wrapper prevents that. On another look at your code, perhaps you didn't even need `Expenses` to be `Codable` as it seems that you're only encoding/decoding `ExpenseItem`